# Laravel の認証にでてくる 'throttle:6,1' の内容について知りたい

Tags: laravel

Laravel9の認証周りを調べているとき、
`->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])`　というコードを頻繁に見かけました。
`signed` は期限付きURL ということでした
`throttle` はアクセス制限だと思います。

throttle の右にある数値にて「1分間に6回」という制限かと…
ただ、公式でそれらの記述を見つけられなくてモヤモヤしています。
（コード例は山ほどありますが、その内容を書いているものは極わずか。ほぼAPI関係）

探し出せないだけかもしれないのですがご存知でしたら「ここに書いてあるよ！」と教えて頂けると嬉しいです。
ソースから見るべき場合は、どのソースを見ればよいか教えてもらえるでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThrottleRequestsミドルウェアのAPIドキュメントは https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html#method_handle

その実際のコードは
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php

テストコードは
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/tests/Integration/Http/ThrottleRequestsTest.php

にあります。
認識されている通り、1分間に6回のアクセス制限です。

そもそもどうやってそのキーワードからこのミドルウェアが解釈されるか？という話であれば[`Http\Kernel`で登録している](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4135d5834505e3253e6ff8a68180bf40dfb50112/app/Http/Kernel.php#L64)からですが、これについては今更でしょうか。

なお、スロットリングにRedisの機能を使用する[ThrottleRequestsWithRedis](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequestsWithRedis.php)も選択可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
まだまだ学び始めで情報を探し出すのに苦労しています。
参考にさせていただきます！